# Setting scripts/rel in head tag of html layout in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I started a new laravel application, and currently working on the main html template layout, I faced a issue.

I made a helper class that could set "version", so I can refresh the cache when I have new release.

```
namespace App\Http\Helpers;


class HTML
{
    private const VERSION = '20180515';

    private static function setVersion(&$file): void
    {
        $file = $file . '?v=' . self::VERSION;
    }

    public static function style(string $file): string
    {
        self::setVersion($file);

        return '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $file . '">';
    }

    public static function script(string $file): string
    {
        self::setVersion($file);

        return '<script src="' . $file . '"></script>';
    }
}
```

And in the layout I use this:

```
...    
<head>
...
    {{ \App\Http\Helpers\HTML::style('css/layout.css') }}
</head>
```

Is there a way to **use** the HTML helper class so I don't have to call the namespaces every time?

Answer (score 0):

Include in `config/app.php`

```
...

'aliases' => [
    ....
    'HTML' => \App\Http\Helpers\HTML::class,
 ],
```

HTML is a common word and you may have some issues. If you have, use a differente key.

Anyway, you can then use

```
{!! HTML::style('css/layout.css') !!}
```

Also, if you have any issue, run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing - putting the method in {{ }}, escapes the string and it becomes invalid for the head, so it gets printed on the page. Did you change those on purpose?